# I need some help on this Chemistry question can any one help please!! I need to find the cost of a single atom of aluminum

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

A 75 ft2 roll of aluminum foil costs $3.79.  A 12"x12" pieces has a mass of 1.0 g.  How much does a single atom of aluminum cost, in dollars?
i need to show all my work i am so lost.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that 75 square feet costs \$3.79, so 1 square foot costs \$3.79 divided by 75, or just over 5 cents. We are also given the mass of one square foot as 1.0g, so from the atomic weight of aluminium, one mole costs approximately 27 times this, or \$1.36. One mole is $6.022\times10^{23}$ items (in this case atoms), so how much does an atom cost?

Adjust significant figures to taste.

Comment: could you show me how you got the 27 times and $1.36. im sorry im so  lost

Comment: The atomic mass of aluminum is $26.98 \text{ g/mole }\approx 27$

Comment: thanks for fixing the formatting, MaxW - I tried the "/$" but that kept messing up for me.